# Simplifying this radical expression?

Tags: radicals, fractions

We are given:

$ f(x) = √x - 2e^x$

and we have to calculate the difference quotient ($\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h})$

So what I have so far is:

$ \frac{√(x+h)-2e^{(x+h)} - (√x - 2e^x)}{h} $

I would assume you would multiply the numerator by the conjugate correct?:

($ {√(x+h)+2e^{(x+h)} + (√x + 2e^x))} $

Comment: It would be better to first separate the functions into two parts, the square root part and the exponential part, use the conjugate only on the square root part and factor $e^x$ out of the numerator of the exponential part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{√(x+h)-2e^{(x+h)} - (√x - 2e^x)}{h}=\frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h}-2\frac{e^{x+h}-e^{x}}{h}$ by multiplying the numerator and denominator of the first term with $\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}$, we have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}-2e^{x}\frac{e^{h}-1}{h}$

Comment: That definitely makes sense! I always seem to forget that you can separate the fractions. Thank you!